# How to hide empty values in Chart

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I've got a chart, that builds from some data.

Some data is empty, null, but it still shows in chart. I want to show only that data, that has something.

I'll better show you:
[image: Chart]

So, as you can see , there's a lot of labels showing 0%. I want, that they would not showing.

How can I manage it?

Answer (score 0):

JasperReport Server charts show the data whatever you fetch from the database through your SQL query.

So you need to add the where condition in SQL query which fetch the data you want to see in pie chart.

Where condition will be like this :-

```
Select * from Table_name       
Where value_column > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ireport you should use filter expression in the chart.